# issue focusing QLineEdit rendered to QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qt4, overlay

I render Qt gui elements on my own 3d application screen by rendering Qt stuff to QImage and then drawing that on the screen. I redirect input to QGraphicsScene, but not everything works. Clicking buttons works fine while clicking QLineEdit or web page elements in QWebView doesnt. However doubleclick seems to work - doubleclicked QLineEdit would select some text, but still would not gain focus. What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using `QGraphicsProxyWidget`s to wrap these controls?

Comment: ehm no, i am not. going to investigate it!

Comment: See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget

Comment: hmm i checked it out, havent found anything new. i do addWidget(), and it is rendered fine, but i fail to see how to make all elements work properly, now ones work when clicked.. the other ones - not quite

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It seemed i had

```
QGraphicsView.keyPressEvent(self, keyEvent)
```

implemented in my graphicsView. Had to resend the event up the chain of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I also implemented keyboard event sending. No matter how i send events (QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent()/QGraphicsScene::keyReleaseEvent() or QApplication::sendEvent) text is not typed into control, even if some text is selected in QLineEdit (text should be overwritten, shouldnt it?). I suspect this is because of QLineEdit not gaining focus by clicking it, but i cant find out why it is not focused. All events are sent to my subclass of QGraphicsScene.